# Away3D 4.0 Loading dynamic textures for primitives from arrays

Tags: actionscript, dynamic, textures, primitive, away3d

I have several arrays storing the attributes needed to build primitives.  One array stores the widths, another stores the heights, another the depths, x, y, z etc.  I have one more that stores the remote filename for the texture to be applied.  After I get my response from the server I attempt to apply the textures to the primitives.  When I move the camera to look at the primitive, I am not able to see it.  My view seems to freeze up (the view will not update).  Once the camera has moved past the primitive, it can see again.  Any ideas?

```
private var loadedBuildingTextures:Object = new Object();
private var map_building_count:Number = 0;
private var loadedBuildings:Number = 0;
public var map_building_widths:Array;
public var map_building_heights:Array;
public var map_building_depths:Array;
public var map_building_xs:Array;
public var map_building_ys:Array;
public var map_building_zs:Array;
public var map_building_textures:Array;

// I POPULATE THE ARRAYS BUT LEFT THAT CODE OUT FOR SIMPLICITY

public function placeBuildings():void {
 trace('FUNCTION: placeBuildings() fired');
 var buildingsPlaced:Number = 0;
 for (var a:Number = 0; a < map_building_count; a++ ) {
  loadedBuildingTextures['texture_' + a.toString()] = new BitmapFileMaterial(map_building_textures[a]); // ASSIGNS THE BitmapFileMaterials TO AN OBJECT FOR REFERENCING LATER
  loadedBuildingTextures['texture_' + a.toString()].loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, postBuildingLoad);
  buildingsPlaced++;
 }
 trace('placed ' + buildingsPlaced.toString() + ' of ' + map_building_count.toString() + ' buildings.'); // OUTPUT = "placed 4 of 4 buildings."
 trace('FUNCTION: placeBuildings() completed');
}

public function postBuildingLoad(event : Event):void {
 loadedBuildings++;
 if (int(loadedBuildings) == int(map_building_count)) {
  placeBuildingsStep2();
 }
}
public function placeBuildingsStep2():void {
 trace('RECEIVED ALL RESPONSES FROM SERVER FOR TEXTURES');
 for (var a:Number = 0; a < map_building_count; a++ ) {
  cube = new Cube(
   loadedBuildingTextures['texture_' + a], // <----- THIS SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM
   map_building_widths[a], // WIDTH
   map_building_heights[a], // HEIGHT
   map_building_depths[a], // DEPTH
   1, // WIDTH UNITS
   1, // HEIGHT UNITS
   1,  // DEPTH UNITS
   true);
  cube.x = map_building_xs[a];
  cube.y = map_building_ys[a];
  cube.z = map_building_zs[a];
  view.scene.addChild(cube);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this post is old, it does highlight an important issue. BitmapFileMaterial is more a shortcut to test than a production ready scheme.

I would highly recommend using a loading queue for external assets (like [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) or the new [AssetLibrary](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/library/AssetLibrary.html) in 4.0) and then instantiate materials as needed.